# Timing of a certain hour on Friday

Tags: dua

aslam alaykum,

can you please define the timings of the particular hour on Friday in which if u ask for anything good it is given to u. Do i have to make supplication all the day in order to meet that hour or are there any particular timing from which i have to start and end making dua.

Please define the timing because i heard its the entire day not just the time between kutba and the time after asar so please clear this confusion.

Comment: Supplication doesn't work that way. You can supplicate your entire life and you won't get what you ask for.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are lot's of ahadith quoting the existence of a certain hour in Friday in which what you ask in a supplication would be given to you.

There are even some narrations which give a more or less exact timing. And some scholars do qualify some of these timings as better or worse. as you may read in this [Fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/82609) or here in [Arabic/Urdu](http://islamqa.info/ar/201556).

But i think supplication is an act between a human and his creator, so if the timing was fixed and well known then why should one do his best to worship Allah and do supplication at any time of the day? I mean somehow it would be strange if people get what they want without an effort. And that's all the same with the hour of [the night](http://sunnah.com/muslim/6/200) and the laylatul Qadr, again we know it's a night in Ramadan, and there are ahadith quoting a certain night or certain nights but who really knows which night it is? This is my opinion and Allah knows best!

Here are the most sahih ahadith on the matter:
In Sahih [al-Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/11/59) and [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/7/23) and others all narrated by Abu Huraira.
And a narration by Jabir ibn Abdullah in [Sunan an-Nasa'i](http://sunnah.com/nasai/14/26).

And a narration in [Jami' at-Timridhi](http://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/4/4) with an indication for the hour

And a hadith with a different indication in [Sahih Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/7/25)

And here some ahadith which have been qualified as hassan from [Jami' at-Tirmdihi](http://sunnah.com/urn/743870) and [Sunan ibn Majah](http://sunnah.com/urn/1311920).

And Allah knows best!