# When is the time of response mentioned in this following hadith?

Tags: dua, authenticity

I have read a hadith that says, every night there is an hour when no Muslim asks Allah of anything and he will be given that. Can anyone tell me is there any record or authentic opinion about when this time might be? I have read about the hour of response on Friday, but don't know about the hour of response at every night. Is it the last third of night as Allah(SWT) descends to the last heaven described in another hadith? Or is it referring some different time period of the night?

Comment: Related or similar http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/28428/timing-of-a-certain-hour-on-friday

Comment: i think this hour is unknown like al-qadr night but there is another hadith more helpfull https://sunnah.com/bukhari/19/26

Comment: At the moment we are 2 billion Muslims in the world. I don't think there is a second free where no Muslim asks Allah of nothing. Also your night is the day for millions of other Muslims. But of course this might be explained as only in places where it is night.